# Did Prince ever license his music to advertisers?

Tags: prince

Dior recently premiered [a new advertisement](https://www.dior.com/en_us/makeup/rouge-dior-the-new-couture-lipstick) for their "reinvented" Rouge Dior lipstick; it stars Natalie Portman and is soundtracked by Prince's "Raspberry Beret". Two years ago they also had an advertisement for one of their lipsticks which also starred Portman, and that one used Prince's "Kiss".

Did anything similar ever happen while Prince was alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it was rare, Prince did on occasion license his music for usage in advertisements.

This is a likely incomplete list:

- Prince sold a clip of **"Little Red Corvette"** from [his ***Sign O' The Times*** concert movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_o%27_the_Times_(film)) to Chevrolet.
- **Tina Turner**'s [cover of **"Baby I'm A Star"**](https://tinaturnerblog.com/2012/09/27/baby-shes-a-star/) was used by Target (and yes, Prince had to approve that).
- CBS's ***The Super Bowl Today*** on 26 January 1992 featured an alternate version of the video Prince filmed for "Willing And Able", featuring ["footage of football players lip-syncing the lyrics"](https://princevault.com/index.php?title=Video:_Willing_And_Able). As [reported in Daily Press](https://www.dailypress.com/1992/01/27/cbs-gets-high-marks-for-its-super-bowl-coverage/):

  > The pre-game broadcast began with the world premiere of Minneapolis native Prince’s new video for his new song ”Willing and Able.” The video contained film of Bills and Redskins players in action. However, Prince’s falsetto voice did not provide very appropriate accompaniment for this footage.

  The [Tampa Bay Times reported](https://www.tampabay.com/archive/1992/01/26/tv-radio-lineup/):

  > The lineup
  >
  > 3:30-4 p.m.: The Super Bowl Today opening is a music video by Minneapolis native Prince, who will perform the unreleased single Willing and Able. **Prince delayed the release of the single so it could be released in conjunction with the Super Bowl.** Players from both the Washington Redskins and Buffalo Bills lip-sync to the rap portion of the song.
- Prince wrote [a song titled **"Coca-Cola"**](http://www.princevault.com/index.php?title=Coca-Cola).

  > It is believed that the track was written as a theme for the Coca-Cola Company, and most likely in particular for their Coca-Cola soft drink (the Coca-Cola Company sponsored [the Act II Tour in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_I_and_II)). The track's lyrics indicate that it was recorded for a commercial (including "Life is exciting, oh yeah, but when you've got the real thing, it's better. Coca-Cola, go get some, it's the real thing. Always Coca-Cola.")
- The [1993 Act II Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_I_and_II) was sponsored by Coca-Cola and each concert was littered with ads for it: on the video screens, on the tickets (the image below comes courtesy of [Unused-Prince-Tickets.com](http://unused-prince-tickets.com/1993.html)),... There was even a sphere with the Coca-Cola logo at the mix desk (IIRC).

  [image: unused ticket for Prince's 1993 Act II tour]
- Prince's [**"Guitar"**](http://www.princevault.com/index.php?title=Guitar) was used by Verizon in a video he filmed for them.

  > six weeks prior to the album’s release, the album version of Guitar was available for download on Verizon Wireless in the USA, and a short promotional clip of Prince and his band performing the song was used in TV advertisements.

  You can find more info about the Prince/Verizon collaboration [in this flyer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCwfc.jpg).
- [**"Dreamer"**](http://www.princevault.com/index.php?title=Dreamer) was used in [a Target ad](https://www.jasonwebb.xyz/princedreamer) for [the ***Lotusflow3r*** album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotusflow3r) (this video was specifically filmed for the ad AFAIK).
- Allegedly [**"Wow"** (a.k.a. **"The Unexpected"**)](http://www.princevault.com/index.php?title=Wow) was intended for a commercial for Coca-Cola or Pepsi.

Comment: You’re quite good at answering your own questions.

Comment: @cmp I'd researched it for another purpose, and decided that I could just as well share it here. This way I'd also be able to point at this whenever the topic comes up, plus since the StackExchange sites are well represented in Google, it will make it easier for someone else to find.

Comment: A few years ago, a [Continental commercial](https://m.ina.fr/video/PUB2346244053/continental-pneu-surfeur-femme-video.html) featured the song [*La La La Means I love you*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAOpXrb1Qqs) (from the album *Emancipation*). Back then, I remember thinking "Wow, they're so stupid, they could have taken the song [*Continental*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vb7Yo3zQXH0) (from *The New Power Generation*)".

Comment: @Bebs Not a Prince song.